# interpreting inequalities

Tags: inequality

I’m working on a set of inequalities, but I don’t understand much of these, its about to state the possible values of $2D$ based on

$$0<\frac{2D}{\sqrt(M)\sqrt(K)}<1$$

I did this

$$\frac{2D}{\sqrt(M)\sqrt(K)}-1<0=\frac{2D}{\sqrt(M)\sqrt(K)}-\frac{\sqrt(M)\sqrt(K)}{\sqrt(M)\sqrt(K)}<0=\frac{2D-\sqrt(M)\sqrt(K)}{\sqrt(M)\sqrt(K)}<0$$
so it means that

- $2D-\sqrt(M)\sqrt(K)<0$ and $\sqrt(M)\sqrt(K)\geq0$
  then ¿$0<2D\leq\sqrt(M)\sqrt(K)$?
- $2D-\sqrt(M)\sqrt(K)>0$ and $\sqrt(M)\sqrt(K)\leq0$

¿$2D\geq\sqrt(M)\sqrt(K)$?

is this interpretation about $2D$ right? Thanks

Comment: Note that $\sqrt{x} \ge 0$ with the usual definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close. Assuming the obvious $\;M,K>0\;$, then since $\;\sqrt M,\,\sqrt K>0\;$ too, we get

$$0<\frac{2D}{\sqrt M\sqrt K}<1\; /\;\cdot \sqrt M\sqrt K \implies 0<2D<\sqrt M\sqrt K=\sqrt{MK}$$

Comment: Ok! thanks for the tip.